# Class inside a function causing null pointer exception

Tags: java, android

The following code causes null-pointer exception during execution. It just said null pointer exception.

When I put the hotItem class outside of the function, it works without any problem.

Once I put it into the function, it will cause null pointer exception.

I just want to know why this would happen and what is the life cycle of the class inside a function.

```
private void getHotItem()
{   
    Gson gsonAdapter = new Gson();
    class hotItem
    {
        private String hotItemPK = ""; 
    }
    Type hotItemType = new TypeToken<List<hotItem>>(){}.getType();
    List<hotItem> hotItemList = new ArrayList<hotItem>();

    try
    {
        itemAccess.getHotItemList();
        itemAccess.start();
        itemAccess.join();
        hotItemList = gsonAdapter.fromJson(returnData, hotItemType);

        if(!hotItemList.isEmpty())
        {
            testText.setText(hotItemList.get(0).hotItemPK.toString());
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I found that the problem was caused by: Type hotItemType = new TypeToken<List<hotItem>>(){}.getType(); that return null

Comment: But I don't know why it can't get the type if the class hotItem was inside the function getHotItem()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=408)

Resolution:

> I'm guessing you have both gson.jar AND gson-stream.jar on your class path; that won't work.
>
> The problem is that in Gson 2.1 we have a custom version of JsonReader that adds some secret hooks to make MapTypeAdatperFactory faster; these hooks won't work with gson-stream.jar's version of JsonReader.

Comment: I have checked that return data

Comment: It's not related to the data... the problem was caused by the struct like class. Since I put it outside the function, it works.. If put it inside the function like the code above, it cause null-pointer exception. Just want to know how this happen...

Comment: That just like what I found after a long research on gson.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what might be happening here.

The problem is that `HotItem` is a inner class, and that means it has an implicit reference to an instance of the enclosing class.  But when the `gsonAdapter.fromJson` method attempts to create the `List<HotItem>`, it doesn't have (might not have) an instance of the enclosing class in which to create the `HotItem`.  Depending on how it is doing the creation, it might be creating it with a `null` reference ... and that might be the cause of the NPE.

If this (or something similar) is the problem, then an alternative cure would be to declare `HotItem` to be a `static` class.

---

I should also point that it is BAD STYLE to start a class name with a lower case letter.

Comment: At first, I thought it was somethings wrong with my code and concept about java class, instead I found that the problem was come from gson.

Comment: I use lower case letter for a long while, it's good. At least on C, I might be wrong if using Java.

Comment: You ARE wrong about Java.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367  http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html#Naming%20Conventions and so on.